# Apache service 2.2 not start,give error after change in hhtpd.conf file for php 4 installation

Tags: php, apache2, httpd.conf, installation-path

I have installed php4+ apache server 2.2 . but after editing the file name "httpd.conf" apache server services 2.2 not started.

my code for httpd.conf

```
# LoadModule php_module "php4apache2.dll"
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

  # configure the path to php.ini
    PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

its not works can any body suggest me

Comment: Is that all of your httpd.conf file? There's usually a lot more in there than that

Comment: i have added that code besides to that lot more code [link]http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=ubmeVk4V

Comment: Why are you trying to use a version of PHP that has been outdated for over five years? Support for PHP 4 ended in 2008.

Comment: Is there any output in your error.log or cli when you start it manually?